# Yodlee user sessionToken

Tags: rest, session, token, yodlee

As we use PHP as main system to interact with Yodlee REST API sometimes we receive exceptions that user token expired. What is user sessionToken expiration time? I mean token generated after calling 
*authenticate/login* url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeout for userSessionToken is 30 minutes hence it's recommendable to renew it within 30 minutes.

Comment: Thanks - what are the mechanisms by which we can renew the session?  Is this just done by logging in to Yodlee with the user's username and password to get a new userSessionToken, or is there a (permanent) refresh token somewhere?  I'm really hoping to avoid storing user-supplied credentials locally.

Comment: As of now you will have to logging into Yodlee with the user's username and password to get a new userSessionToken